# How to expand all multi-line comments in FDT 4?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fdt

See title ^

Shortcut or menu option, either is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's the answer - CTRL+Numpad_Multiply

If you don't have a Numpad on your keyboard (like me), then you can edit this by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+L twice to bring up the shortcut editor.